# Can I force R data.table %like% to use "fixed = TRUE"?

Tags: r, regex, data.table, subset

I have a data.table that I want to determine if a set of codes is present in a specific character column. I pass the pattern to `%like%` as a vector of values as illustrated. This syntax works for me; however, I would like to force the `%like%` function to treat each element of the pattern vector as literal, i.e. not use the `.` as a regex wildcard. The manual of data.table says that for the `like` function, it can be set as `fixed = TRUE`. Is there a way I can force my code, using `%like%`, to treat the `.` and `..` as literal rather than wildcards?  Thx. J

This works but treats "." incorrectly as a wildcard:

```
Codes <- c("65E..|9OX..|9OX1.|9OX2.|9OX3.|9OXZ.|Xaa9G")

ActualCodes <- dt[code_id %like% Codes]
```

This does not:

```
Codes <- c("65E..|9OX..|9OX1.|9OX2.|9OX3.|9OXZ.|Xaa9G")

ActualCodes <- dt[code_id %like% Codes, fixed = TRUE]
```

Comment: can you try `dt[like(code_id, Codes, fixed = TRUE)]`.  The issue seems to be that the `fixed = TRUE` is taken as `j` instead of the argument of `like`.   Also, the `|` would be considered literallly in `fixed = TRUE`.  Not clear without a small reproducible example

Comment: I am guessing the best option is to escape your `.` i.e. `Codes <- gsub(".", "\\.", Codes, fixed = TRUE)` and then use the first option

Comment: Thx.  I tried this and no luck, couldn't make it work by escaping the "." in the Codes, using either "\\."   or as the suggestion below suggests, "[.]"   .   Neither seems to work with like function, but good attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the help page for `?'%like%'` you should see that there are two form of `like`. The one that you are attempting to use is the infix, tw0-argument version and does not accept a `fixed =TRUE` argument. I did try to  use the "un-ampersanded" version but failed. What did work was to side-step the "fixed" strategy and instead use a character-class approach to getting "exactly-periods":

```
DT = data.table(Name=c("65E..","65EXX","Xaa9G"), Salary=c(2,3,4))
DT
#---------------
    Name Salary
1: 65E..      2
2: 65EXX      3
3: Xaa9G      4


 
 DT[Name %like% "^Mar"]  # the example was copied from the help page
#Empty data.table (0 rows and 2 cols): Name,Salary
 Codes <- c("65E..|9OX..|9OX1.|9OX2.|9OX3.|9OXZ.|Xaa9G")
 DT[ Name %like%  Codes]
 #   Name Salary
#1: 65E..      2
#2: 65EXX      3       # WRONG, try again
#3: Xaa9G      4  

 
 Codes <- gsub("[.]", "[.]", Codes, fixed = TRUE)  #doesn't succeed
 Codes
#[1] "65E..|9OX..|9OX1.|9OX2.|9OX3.|9OXZ.|Xaa9G"  # wrong result, no matches

 Codes <- gsub("[.]", "[.]", Codes)   # remove "fixed", character class succeeds
 Codes
#[1] "65E[.][.]|9OX[.][.]|9OX1[.]|9OX2[.]|9OX3[.]|9OXZ[.]|Xaa9G"
 DT[ Name %like%  Codes]
# --- correct result----
    Name Salary
1: 65E..      2
2: Xaa9G      4   # SUCCESS
```

Comment: Thx IRTFM, this seems to work, perhaps the data.table package needs some revision/update?  I realise it is a strange example, why put in codes like . or * that will almost certainly cause problems?  These are "Read" codes, used to record medical data in the UK until recently, were developed by a Physician a long time ago, probably before computerisation of data .

Comment: I was unable to get the ordinary `like` function to work with my simple data.table example. I don't know why. My guess is that it is intended for rowwise operations in the J position but I haven't tested that theory. You've got the data.table tag so maybe its maintainer will get this. Otherwise maybe I'll submit an issue to his data.table github page.